# Pandas : 'to_datetime' function not consistent with dates

Tags: python, pandas, date

When I read a date say `'01/12/2020'`, which is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, with `pd.to_datetime()`,  it detects the month as `01`.

```
pd.to_datetime('01/12/2020').month
>> 1
```

But this behavior is not consistent.

When we create a dataframe with a column containing dates in this format, and convert using the same `to_datetime` function, it then detects `12` as the month.

```
tt.dt.month[0]
>> 12
```

What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas automagically tries to detect the date format, which can be very nice, or annoying in your case.

Be explicit, use the `dayfirst` parameter:

```
pd.to_datetime('01/12/2020', dayfirst=False).month
# 1

pd.to_datetime('01/12/2020', dayfirst=True).month
# 12
```

Example of ambiguous use:

```
tt = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['30/05/2020', '01/12/2020']))
tt.dt.month

UserWarning: Parsing dates in DD/MM/YYYY format when dayfirst=False (the default) was specified. This may lead to inconsistently parsed dates! Specify a format to ensure consistent parsing.
  tt = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['30/05/2020', '01/12/2020']))

0    5
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Great. In my case the second date ```'01/12/2020'``` when in dataframe (without supplying ```dayfirst```) was giving month as 12! I know its ambigous and so its possible, but that's really strange. As to_datetime() should be having a DEFAULT way to accept dates.

Comment: @Salih if you want to be fully explicit and trigger an error (or replace with NaN in case of error), use `format='%d/%m/%Y'` ± `errors='coerce'`